# Si7021 CRC check sum I2C validation

Tags: embedded

From I2C communication with Si7021 sensor i got 3 bytes as a result.
MS LS and checksum as shown in the manual bellow.
But how do i validate using checksum my MS and LS bytes.
I know that each device has unique condition.
How do i accomplish that?
Thanks.

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf

[image]

Comment: First, if you want this you need to read the additional value which is the checksum.  Then you need to learn how to calculate this particular CRC.  I suggest you do some web searches on such concepts.  When you've locally calculated the CRC, you can compare it.  I'd suggest maybe you first get some serial logging going in your firmware and log out the raw values.  Then you write a test CRC implementation on your PC and compare the sent values to the calculated expectation. Once you are getting matches (at least most of the time) move the calculation and check into the embedded device.

Comment: I have read MS and LS Chacksum.Is there a source i could use ,i read in the internet that each component has its own criteria. I am looping for and example.